# Python array([]) function

Tags: python, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I tried printing a variable in a python code that I have and I got this:

```
[array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  0.])]
```

What does this code snippet mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a list containing Numpy [`arrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), although without more information I can't assure that.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> my_var = [array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  0.])]
>>> print(my_var)
 [array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  0.])]

>>> print(type(my_var)) 
 <type 'list'>
>>> print(type(my_var[0]))
 <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: You are right about the numpy array!
But I had to print using:
        print(type(my_var[0][0]))
otherwise I got for some reason:
        <type 'list'>
That was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should best know, what it means. It is a list with four array-objects.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same array as the one in the built in array module, then the constructor requires a typecode in order to properly initialize the object , in your case like so : `array('d', [1. ,0.])` . Are you sure the code you have here works ? Assuming it could infer the typecode from the values passed into the initializer list, you would have a list of arrays

Comment: It's almost certainly a list of numpy arrays. One can tell by the specific formatting in `repr`, which the built-in Python arrays don't do. They would get represented as `[array('d', [1.0, 0.0]), ...]`